# How do I call this function using onclick in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just started maintaining someones code and I am not sure whats going on here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     function Test() {

        var that = this;
        that.testFunc = function() {
        }
     }    
}
```

I want to execute that testFunc onclick from HTML. How do I do this? Anyway I can also simplify this? I am confused on this coding style

Comment: I am talking about button onclick

<button onclick="....">Test</button>

Comment: Edit the question too

Comment: Okay, you see the document.ready you have wrapped everything in? That is a method that calls the function that it is passed to it when the document is ready. Use the same pattern to add onclick event handlers. (get dom element).addClickHandler(Test)

Comment: why not use jQuery's `.click()` method?

Comment: In your posted code, `this` is the window object, so calling `Test()` essentially creates a global function named `testFunc`.

Comment: Question? Who is marking every ones code down and not leaving comments? I marked peoples back up because they do work.

Comment: mine is still down. I dont know whats happening here! Amused!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<button onclick="...">`. If you're using jQuery, get the element using [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and set up an [event listener](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

```
$('button').click(function(){
    ...
});
```

The code you've posted it a bit barmy, and not readable. It could use refactoring.

If you insist on leaving it how it is, you can do this...:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     function Test() {
        var that = this;
        that.testFunc = function() {
            //alert('i will also fire when this.testFunc() is called.');
        }

        // alert('i will fire');
        this.testFunc();
     }  

    $('button').click(function(){
       Test(); 
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle of that working.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/xcvqwwyb/)

The coding-style is a poor attempt at OO-Javascript. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) *(I know...)* could be a good place to start understanding what it's all about. Alternatively, [this post on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) is all about the `this` keyword, and has some links to great resources.

TLDR; Code looks really clever, but is just confusing and rubbish.

**Update**

Ok, so here's what happens.

```
$(document).ready(function () {        // when the page is loaded, run this function
    function Test() {                  // create a named function called Test. 
                                       // Note that this function is only visible (so can only be called) within the anonymous function being run after $(document).ready.
        var that = this;               // set a variable ('that') to 'this' - a special keyword. At this point, 'this' will refer to the Global scope.
        that.testFunc = function() {   // create a function called testFunc on the object which is now 'that' - i.e. Global scope, the Window object.
                                       // basically, create window.testFunc.
            //alert('i will also fire when this.testFunc() is called.');
        }

        // alert('i will fire');
        this.testFunc();               // call window.testFunc();
    }  

    $('button').click(function(){
        Test();                        // run the Test function explained above
    });
});
```

So, if you don't refactor, you need to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Test(){
        var that = this;
        that.testFunc = function(){
            ...
        };
    }

    $('button').click(function(){
        testFunc();
    });
    Test();
});
```

Basically, you need to run Test() to create `testFunc` as part of the Global Scope. The code is difficult to follow, and can easily be misinterpreted - so I implore you to refactor and get it done properly.

[Here's (another) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/ff2Lmo96/) of the button just calling `testFunc`.

Comment: The code in the question is obviously just a fragment of the entire thing; it's not really enough to say it's "rubbish" without knowing what it's for and what the context is.

Comment: It's got a named function not set as a `var`, has `var that=this;` rather than using a decent scoping technique, and uses `that.func = function(){...}` instead of the perfectly acceptable `this.func = function(){...}`. The mixing of `this`,`that`, named functions and anonymous functions set as `var`'s is enough for me to deem the code as crap, even if it is only a tiny fragment.

Comment: wouldnt the button click invoke the entire Test() function. I am just trying to invoke the testFunc() function insidei t

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be using the `.click()` method in jQuery.

```
$('.element').click(testFunc);
```

If you want/need to use the HTML `onClick` attribute:

```
<input type="button" onclick="testFunc();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calling `testFunc()` from the handler should be enough, since `testFunc` is being assigned to the window context. That is, assuming `Test()` is called at some point.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/e5r8ss96/2/)